# Apache Tomcat sendRedirect

Tags: jakarta-ee, networking, tomcat

I have an apache tomcat server which is running on a server with one network interface with local IP like LOCALIP but users want to see the server on a public IP like PUBLICIP  and they shouldn't see the server on the local IP. All this configurations made on a hardware firewall.

Users use the address PUBLICIP/mainpage for accessing the application and application checks if the user is authenticated or not.  If user is not authenticated the user redirected to PUBLICIP/login.
When user redirectd to /login page he will see the Page Not Found (404) but if he type PUBLICIP/login address manually in his browser he can see the login page.

We use HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect for redirecting users to the login page.

I think it is a redirection problem because any ping requests to the PUBLICIP will be dropped by the firewall due to security concerns. The servlet tries to redirect to public IP address.

Comment: what are the security concerns here? Also can you paste your piece of code that does redirect and authentication

Comment: We use cas for authentication and we override commence method of CasProcessingFilterEntryPoint class. In the end of commnece method whe use HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(VALIDIP/login). Our server is behinde a NAT and the security concern is we don't want users see the server directly with VALIDIP.

Comment: Can you see what's the redirect header actually being sent?
You can test using the telnet client, e.g.
telnet PUBLICIP 80
Then type:
GET / HTTP/1.0<enter><enter>

What's the reply?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one uses proxyPort and proxyName on the [Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) to tell Tomcat the public IP/DNS name and port that is being used by a reverse proxy (such as a firewall / load-balancer) to ensure that links (such as redirects) generated by Tomcat use the public IP/name and port.